# invalid query parameters: invalid %-encoding

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, multipartform-data, okhttp

I try to upload a picture(jpg) via Retrofit / Multipart. The Api always returns code 400 with "invalid query parameters: invalid %-encoding"
I don't know whats wrong.

My interface:

```
@Headers("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept: application/vnd.mypb+json; version=7")
@POST("/alerts/actions/unknown_pid")
@Multipart
fun uploadPhoto(@Part body: MultipartBody.Part): Call<String?>
```

My webservice upload photo method:

```
fun uploadPhoto(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    val imageFile = File(context.cacheDir, "image.jpg")

    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 15, baos)
    val byteArray = baos.toByteArray()

    val fos = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
    fos.write(byteArray)
    fos.flush()
    fos.close()

    val filePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageFile)
    val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("document[file]", "photo.jpg", filePart)

    service.uploadPhoto(body).enqueue(object : LoggingCallback<String?>() {
        override fun onSuccess(responseBody: String?) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(OnPhotoUploadSuccessfulEvent())
        }

        override fun onFailure(response: Response<String?>) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(OnPhotoUploadFailedEvent())
        }
    })
}
```

Charles response:
[image: Charles response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header is not correct.

You can delete the headers `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

or you should change to `Content-type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: my god...I tried every kind of Content-type but nothing worked. Now I completely delete the Content-type and it works. You saved my day! Thank you